# Java: return results from Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, return, runnable

Suppose the following simplified example. Let B represent a class processing some raster data:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class B implements Runnable{
    private boolean c;
    private Runnable f;

    public B (boolean c_, Runnable f_) { c = c_; f = f_;}

    public BufferedImage process() {
            //Some operations
            BufferedImage output = null;
            if (c) output = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            return output;
    }

    public void run() { process();}
}
```

The **process()** method may but may not create an output rater. Due to the computational cost, the procedure runs in a separate thread.

Let A represent a class inside which the procedure will be run. It also contains some post process steps waiting until the thread is finished:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class A {
    public A(){}
    public void compute() {
            boolean c = true;
            B b = new B( c, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            //Post process, after the thread has been finished
                            BufferedImage img = ??? //Get resulting raster, how?
                            if (img != null) {
                                    //Perform some steps
                            }
                    }
            });

            Thread t = new Thread(b);
            t.start ();  //Run  procedure
    }
}
```

However, how to get resulting raster created using the **process()** method of B "inside" the **run()** method in A?

Avoid the model, when the output image represents a data member of B together with

```
b.getImage();
```

I read a post about callbacks

[Return value from Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771412/return-value-from-runnable)

but how to implement it here? Thanks for your help and a short example.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Callable`.

Comment: You're basically asking "how do I return a value from a method that returns `void`?".  So I think you want a `Callable`, not `Runnable`.

Comment: It looks like you're passing a callback to B but not actually calling it? (variable `f`) You should just call `f()` with the result of `process()` in `B`.

Comment: @ misaka: I am C++ progammer. May I ask you for the example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), specifically  it [`submit(Callable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) method which returns a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) or [`isDone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) methods can be called to retrieve the result:

```
public class B implements Callable<BufferedImage> {
    private boolean c;

    public B (boolean c) { this.c = c; }

    public BufferedImage call() {
        //Some operations
        if (!c)
            return null;
        return new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
}

// Somewhere, e.g. in your A.compute() method

ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); // Two threads in parallel
B b = new B(true);
Future<BufferedImage> res = exe.submit(b); // Will return immediately. Processing will run in a thread of 'exe' executor
// ... do things
System.out.println("Finished: "+res.isDone());
BufferedImage img = res.get(); // Will block until image is available (i.e. b.call() returns)
```

You can use different flavors of `ExecutorService` in which you can queue processings which may (`submit(Callable)`) or may not ([`execute(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable))) return a result. The type of Executor you want to use depends on the type of processing and order you need.

Comment: @ Matthieu: May I kindly ask you for an example?

Comment: @justik I updated with a simple example, somewhat linked to the code you gave

Comment: Thanks @Yahya, `Executors` and `Future` are a must-know for concurrent programming! :)

Comment: You're right, I will, but I'm still have the habit of thinking myself writing in C like the old days. I really need to consider going with the flow :)

Comment: @Yahya (and others as well): the huge advantage with `ExecutorService` is you can tune it to allow for graceful degradation of System resources, by e.g. tuning the number of threads running concurrently, or to schedule processes later in time, repeating, etc. Welcome to the wonderful world of OOP (I made the C > Java jump a few years ago and don't regret it :)).

Comment: @ Matthieu: Merci et bonne soirée :-)

Comment: @ Yahya: the same problem, I am an old-school C++ programmer and Java is sometimes like the black-box :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like this:

```
public class B{
    private boolean c;
    volatile boolean finished = false; // it can be shared among threads
    BufferedImage output;

    public B (boolean c_) { c = c_;}

    public void process() {
       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (c) output = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                finished = true;
            }       
       });
       t.start();         
   }
}
```

---

```
public class A {
   public void compute() {
      B b = new B(true);
      b.process();
      while(!b.finished){System.out.println("Processing");}
      // when finished check if output is not null
      // and then do some stuff
      if(b.output!=null){System.out.println(b.output);}
   }
}
```

Comment: @Matthieu I've never got to know `Future` but glad to end up with something a bit similar according to ya.

Comment: @ Yaha: thanks, but "Avoid the model, when the output image represents a data member of B together with"...

Comment: @Yahya when used properly, it is a very powerful tool :)