# Callable in a separate thread vs. Runable and mulitasking

Tags: java, multithreading, multitasking, callable

Sorry for my slightly "beginner" question related to the running of computations in a separate thread, but I am a C++ programmer.

There is a computationally expensive task processing large images. During the processing I would like to be able to work with my software (including zoom operations).

Based on your [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000623/java-return-results-from-runnable) (the procedure returns data - a new image)
the Callable interface has been used:

```
public class B implements Callable<BufferedImage> {
   private boolean c;

   public B (boolean c) { this.c = c; }

   public BufferedImage call() {
       //Some operations
       if (!c)
           return null;
       return new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
}
```

Initially, the executor service is created:

```
ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); 
B b = new B(true);
```

Subsequently, the future is returned:

```
Future<BufferedImage> res = exe.submit(b);
```

Finally, we are waiting for the data:

```
BufferedImage img = res.get();
```

Unfortunately, this implementation does not behave the way I expected. Although it works in a separate thread, the "response" is not returned to the main window and I am not able to work with the software properly **during the computation**.

Therefore, I tried to modify the get() method so that

```
try
{
    BufferedImage img_proj = results.get(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

catch (Exception e)
{
     results.cancel(true);
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, the TimeoutException appears. Rewriting the code back using the Runnable interface

```
public class B implements Runnable{
    private boolean c;
    private Runnable f;

    public B (boolean c_, Runnable f_) { c = c_; f = f_;}

    public BufferedImage process() {
            //Some operations
            BufferedImage output = null;
            if (c) output = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            return output;
    }

    public void run() { process();}
}
```

together with

```
Thread t = new Thread(b);
t.start ();
```

and the multitasking works as expected...

So my question is: Is it necessary to "tune" or tweak the Callable interface additionally and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using your executor service.

```
exe.submit(()->{
    BufferedImage img = res.get();
    uiRelatedMethod(img);
});
```

That way your gui thread doesn't block, and it will get notified once the buffered image is available. Of course you'll have to use a try/catch block.

Comment: @ matt: Thanks. What does mean res here? In my code Future<BufferedImage> res represents a result of the submit procedure....

Comment: Yes exactly the res from your example. Instead of just calling res.get(), submit res.get as a task to your executor.

Comment: @ matt: It works great... Almost without any change of my current code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedImage img = res.get();
```

This blocks the whole thread where it is called from until the image is calculated.
I assume you call this from your main or UI message dispatch thread, so this is why your UI is blocked.

There are several approaches to solve this:

- Implement a notification mechanism which notifies your UI when an image is calculated completely. You could e.g. pass a Listener to B's constructor, store it, and notify it at the end of the computation.
- Check regularly if your futures are done (`isDone()`), and perform actions then.
- There are also some utility libraries out there providing notification infrastructure around Java Concurrency.

**EDIT: As an example was requested:**

It is hard to give a good example without knowing your complete application, or at least its technology stack.

To avoid implementing an own interface (which I would do in my application), I will re-use Java's ChangeListener interface:

```
public void myButtonWasClicked() {
  // all your stuff setting up executor...

  // yes, this could be written much shorter with Java 8
  ChangeListener myChangeListener = new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
      handleImageReady((BufferedImage)evt.getSource());
    }
  }

  B b = new B(true, myChangeListener);
  exe.submit(b);
}
```

Your B class extended:

```
public class B implements Callable<BufferedImage> {
   private boolean c;

   private ChangeListener listener;

   public B (boolean c, ChangeListener listener) { this.c = c; this.listener = listener; }

   public BufferedImage call() {
       //Some operations
       if (!c)
           return null;
       BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       // pass finished image to listener who will handle in the UI
       listener.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(img));
       return img; // as nobody will consume this any longer, you could as well switch back to Runnable instead of Callable...
    }
}
```

Please note that this is a really rough example for a Java beginner. There would be many things to improve. For example, the Executor service must be shut down somewhere...

Comment: @ Florian: thank for your answer. Could I kindly ask for some example?

Comment: @ Florian: Thank you very much for your illustrative example, Now, it looks easy to understand...